# How many hours do cabin crews work?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-attendant

Flight crews are limited to 100 *flight* hours a month and 1000 *flight* hours a year, and usually paid by flight hour too. But is it the same for cabin crews or do they have their own rules for monthly hours? Is there an aviation regulation regarding them (they are safety critical crew members after all) with an ICAO recommendation, or are they subject to just work laws of their home country?

Comment: Limited by whom? That doesn't sound like a globally valid rule

Comment: @J.Hougaard, I don't know by whom it is limited. That's why I am asking. For pilots it is limited by regulation and as far as I can tell all countries follow the same recommendation.

Comment: Seems like an FAA-specific rule. See https://www.flightdeckfriend.com/how-many-hours-can-pilots-work-in-one-day/ Please add the USA tag if this question is about the USA